# Mongo db oddness at $in

Tags: mongodb

I have an array which contains 30 mongoid, this is my code,

```
$rest = $m->cart->res->find(array("_id" => array('$in' => $restin["e"])))->limit(30)->explain();
```

_id field is indexed naturally, But I get the results like it never indexed, this is my explain result,

```
[cursor] => BtreeCursor _id_ multi
[isMultiKey] => 
[n] => 30
[nscannedObjects] => 30
[nscanned] => 43
[nscannedObjectsAllPlans] => 30
[nscannedAllPlans] => 43
[scanAndOrder] => 
[indexOnly] => 
[nYields] => 0
[nChunkSkips] => 0
[millis] => 0
[indexBounds] => Array
```

The part I dont understand is, why mongodb searches 43 documents ?, there are only 30 indexed mongoids, nscanned should be 30, how can I fix this ?

Comment: Try without the limit and see whether that changes the explain plan

Comment: You are pretty sure that your array has only 30 elements?  By the way, what is your MongoDB version?

Comment: it is 2.2.2, I checked again my array has 30, I tried with 3 mongoids this time and I got the nscanned 5.

Comment: OK, if you execute the same query in the shell, what do you get?  Also please publish that query that you are executing in the shell.

Comment: db.res.find({_id:{$in:[ObjectId("50ad4a456803fab006000000"),ObjectId("509030476803fa0114000000"),ObjectId("509030746803faf60a000002")]}},{_id:1}).explain(), I get nscanned 4

Answer (score 3):

Here is the documentation excerupt from [Mongo DB Explain Plan](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain/#explain-output-fields-core)

Particularly, pay attention to the section where it talks about **COVERED INDEX**.  Your last response was a covered index (as you are projecting only the id: 1), and it looks very normal in any case based on their documentation.

**nscannedObjects**
Specifies the total number of documents scanned during the query. The nscannedObjects may be lower than nscanned, such as if the index is a covered index.

**nscanned**
Specifies the total number of documents or index entries scanned during the database operation. You want n and nscanned to be close in value as possible. The nscanned value may be higher than the nscannedObjects value, such as if the index is a **covered index**.